# How do I add a key (an integer inputted by user) and a value (inputted in a list by user) to a dictionary so I can reference the key later?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm writing a program that would allow the user to add new information about a product. The information is stored in a dictionary. I'm having trouble assigning a key to information stored in a list and adding them to the dictionary.
All variables are inputted by the user so there's no way to know what the next key would be. What's the simplest way? Thanks.

Comment: Is the user going to input `prod_id`? if so then you can use and `if statement` to see if the input matches `prod_id` and then add it to your dictionary.

Comment: If your keys are just going to be an ordered sequence of integers, you might as well use a list.

Comment: I also see no attempt at getting information from the user. Are you asking how to get user input and store it in a variable?

Comment: @ImtiazRaqib yes the user inputs prod_id

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 There is code to get input from the user but I didn't think it was relevant to the question. I'm asking how to make the input (prod_id) a key in a dictionary and the list a value.

Comment: Are you really asking how to refer to a variable's value? Like, `x = 1`, and then you want to get whatever value (`1` in this case) is assigned to `x`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The key is not predictable, it is an accepted input from the user.

Comment: And then it is stored. Again, are you _really_ asking how to refer to a variable's value? In the example of my above comment, `x` evaluates to `1`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 ....sometimes the simplest things are buried in lines of flipping complicated code! :@ I'm disappointed in myself. Thanks for your help lol

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free
   code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers
   (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics
   on [How to ask a good
   question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards,
   please update your question with the code you have written thus far
   in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia If you look at the edits, the question once contained code. I gather OP got embarrassed and removed it.

Comment: @EricM. lol, I would've left it but it's for an assignment. Can't risk people from my class stealing it. It would take too much time to look at the edited version so that's really my basis. We're all clueless sobs.

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`prodList[prod_id] = products`

For what it's worth you have a `dictonary` and not a `list` so you might want to reflect that in your naming.

Comment: I'm aware of the name hahaa, but yes, it's dictionary.  Seems to work.... why have I been killing myself over this T.T. Thank you!